# Fixed Background Image Causing Unwanted Repositioning in iOS Safari?

Tags: css, safari, css-animations, mobile-safari, css-transforms

I have a fixed background image within a div that will not display consistently in mobile Safari. It displays fine when a page is refreshed, but the main issue arises when I try to prompt backward and forward to other site pages, which causes the browser to reposition the background's origin point awkwardly.

**Note: The first image shows the background image displaying correctly, while the second image displays the transform-origin shift that occurs upon navigating back/forward in the Safari mobile browser, (the main issue).**

[image] [image]

Here's a snippet, for further reference:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}

.sitebg {
  background: url("http://maxpixel.freegreatpicture.com/static/photo/1x/Seamless-Repeating-Tiling-Tile-able-Tileable-1889447.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 720px 720px;
  -webkit-animation: 180s rotatebg infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: 180s rotatebg infinite linear;
  -o-animation: 180s rotatebg infinite linear;
  -ms-animation: 180s rotatebg infinite linear;
  animation: 180s rotatebg infinite linear;
  width: 750px;
  height: 750px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.sitebg-parent {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotatebg {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  }
}

@keyframes rotatebg {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform-origin: top left;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform-origin: top left;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="sitebg-parent">
    <div class="sitebg"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why don't you have set the background to body?

Comment: Would that really make a difference?

Comment: Also, because I need for the background to rotate, so I wanted to isolate it from the `body`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! Your code snippet displays the white screen, so I haven't noticed the rotation, sorry.

Comment: @KoshVery No problem. I still have yet to figure out a solution to this. I suspected it could be a caching issue with the mobile browser, but I imagine there should be some way to sustain the position of the background at origin center (X and Y) regardless of navigating backward or forward in the browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the code below.
I've slightly changed your code and removed unnecessary and ivalid css rules.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.sitebg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  width: 2000px; height: 2000px;
  margin: -1000px 0 0 -1000px;
  background: url("http://s3.gomedia.us/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/skullbg-green.gif");
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: 180s rotatebg infinite linear;
  animation: 180s rotatebg infinite linear;
}

.sitebg-parent {
  position: absolute; z-index: -1;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotatebg {
  0% {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg)}
  100% {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg)}
}

@keyframes rotatebg {
  0% {transform: rotateZ(0deg)}
  100% {transform: rotateZ(360deg)}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="sitebg-parent">
    <div class="sitebg"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Great solution! I've implemented this to my site, and it works great! No more background origin shifting, exactly what I was looking for. You really saved the day, thank you!

Comment: @nrweb, happy to help!